# Search for a model given price range in different currencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

**The scenario:**

products are shown in a user-specified currency, while each product has its own original currency (could be same as user specified, could be any other currency)

a user wants to search for products with a specific price range (10 - 100) in their user-specified currency (let's assume USD)

I am using postgres and Rails. Each product has a price_amount and currency for the original currency.

**The problem**
Since each product could be in any currency, I need to normalize all products to be in the user specified currency so I can see which product is in range.

I have the exchange rate for each pair of supported currencies. But the query will be really complex, so I wonder if there is something more efficient?

```
currencies.map do |currency|
 rate = ex_rate(user_specific_currency, currency)
 query = [query , "products.price * #{rate} <= user_max AND products.price * #{rate} >= user_min AND products.currency = '#{currency}'"].join(" OR ") 
end

Product.where(query)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SQL CASE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-conditional.html) for it:

```
SELECT price, currency,
       CASE WHEN currency='USD' THEN price * 1
            WHEN currency='RUB' THEN price * 65
            ELSE price
       END as final_price
FROM products
WHERE final_price BETWEEN 10 AND 100
```

> CASE clauses can be used wherever an expression is valid. Each
>   condition is an expression that returns a boolean result. If the
>   condition's result is true, the value of the CASE expression is the
>   result that follows the condition, and the remainder of the CASE
>   expression is not processed. If the condition's result is not true,
>   any subsequent WHEN clauses are examined in the same manner. If no
>   WHEN condition yields true, the value of the CASE expression is the
>   result of the ELSE clause. If the ELSE clause is omitted and no
>   condition is true, the result is null.

Rails version:

```
Product.select("price, currency, CASE 
  WHEN currency='USD' THEN price * 1  
  WHEN currency='RUB' THEN price * 65 
  ELSE price END as final_price")
.where("final_price BETWEEN ? AND ?", 10, 100)
```

Comment: I will try that. Does activerecord support CASE? do I need to install a postgres extension?

Comment: @NickGinanto CASE is available in pg by default. I don't think active record support any nice way to write it

Comment: ok that helped me but the solution is not quite complete since you can't have an alias from the select in a where clause. so the better answer is to have the case clause in the where clause and not in the select

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
Product.select("price, currency, CASE WHEN currency='USD' THEN price * 1  WHEN currency='RUB' THEN price * 65 ELSE price END as final_price").where("final_price BETWEEN ? AND ?", 10, 100)
```

Hope this will work for you.