# Rails/Postgres: Running queries against Product records stored with different currencies

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, currency

A Product model contains two different prices which are stored in the respective domestic currency (any of ~20 currencies). Users will then search products with a price range given in the user's currency (which could be any currency of the world). I.e. the user may search for products priced between *x* and *y* USD, but the products have prices in EUR, or CHF, or GBP etc. The problem obviously lies in daily changing FX rates.

I am using Rails with Postgres. There will ultimately be some 50k Product instances and a reasonable expectation of (eventually) 100k or more queries per day. Initially I expect ~5k products with ~10k queries per day, run on Heroku.

I have found information about [SQL CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627119/search-for-a-model-given-price-range-in-different-currencies). The resulting SQL query would be very long, given that the database records have ~20 different currencies. Could I expect reasonable performance with the above use case?

Alternatively, I am pondering to declare a main currency - e.g. EUR - and on a daily basis run a cronjob and use the then-valid foreign exchange rates to convert the prices from domestic currencies to EUR. Then when a user runs the search and wants *"all products between 2,000 and 4,000 USD"*, I would first convert the user's USD into EUR and run the query against already stored EUR values that are max. 1 day old. (Suggestions on how to actually do this are welcome. I'm relatively new to Rails and have never set up a cron job.)

Which of these two options should I go for in the described scenario? Or is there an even better way?

Comment: Could you show how the values are stored and if are in different tables, how do they related among themselves ?

Comment: I haven't put it into the code yet just to evalue first what's smarter. Unless I'd use a gem like money-rails it would boil down to three columns: price_domestic, price_foreign (both integers or decimals) and product_currency (likely a string).

Comment: I would absolutely go the second route (price_in_euro). No question.